# Parameter estimation for random variables where a control parameter is another r.v

Tags: estimation, point-estimation, compound-distributions

Let $\{X_i\}$ a sequence of independent random variables.
Each $X_i$ has a p.d.f $p(m, \theta)$. Where $\theta$ is a real unknown parameter and $m$ the outcome of another random variable $M$ with p.d.f $p(m)$.

I have the next protocol to get a sample $\bar{x}=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$:

First, I get the value $m_1 \sim p(m)$. 
Then I obtain the value $x_1 \sim p(m_1 \theta)$. 
And I repeat the process $n$-times.

The aim is to estimate the value of $\theta$ from $\bar{x}$.

My questions:

1. the maximum likelihood estimator is the best way to do that?
2. Are there lower bound inequalities for the variance of the estimator for $\theta$?

When $m$ and $\theta$ are real unknown parameters, I know that there is the Cramér-Rao Bound, and when one has a parameter that is a random variable there exists the Van Trees inequality. But in this situation, I don't know if there is a standard inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

1. I think there is a confusion: it does not really make sense to ask if the MLE is a "good way" to estimate $\theta$. As its name suggests, the MLE is your best estimate of $\theta$ that maximizes the likelihood of your observation, so yes, it is pretty good ^^ But a more relevant question is *how* to obtain your MLE. Given that you have both *observed* variables $X_i$ and *hidden* variables $M_i$, I would suggest using the [Expectation-Maximization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm).
2. You can indeed use the Cramér-Rao bound. In this case, the likelihood used to compute the Fisher Information is the likelihood of your observations $X_i$, obtained by marginalizing the joint distribution of the observed and hidden variables:

$$
p(X_i|\theta) = \sum_{M_i}p(X_i|M_i,\theta)p(M_i)
$$

I highly recommend this article, in which the authors use the EM algo to obtain the MLE of a vector of parameters $\theta$, and also compute the Fisher Information matrix: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4867027/

Answer (score 0):

The (complete information) likelihood in this model is$$\prod_i p(x_i|m_i,\theta)\tag{1}$$which can be maximised or used in a Bayesian analysis, providing a prior $p(\theta)$ is chosen. (There is no "best way to estimate" a quantity, it all depends on the utility function for running the estimation.)

In the event the $m_i$'s are *not observed*, the (observed) likelihood becomes$$\prod_i \int p(x_i|m,\theta)\,p(m)\,\text{d}m\tag{2}$$

If there exists an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ in this setting, $T_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n|m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ then it satisfies the [Cramér-Rao
inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Multivariate_case)$$\text{cov}(T_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n|m_1,\ldots,m_n)) \ge I_n^{-1}(\theta;m_1,\ldots,m_n)$$where $I_n(\theta;m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ is the (complete) Fisher information matrix associated with (1):
$$I_n(\theta;m_1,\ldots,m_n)=-\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}_\theta \left[
 \dfrac{\partial ^2}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^\text{T}} \log p\left(X| m_i,{\theta}\right)\right]$$
Once again, if the $m_i$'s are *not observed*, the observed Fisher information become
$$I_n(\theta)=-n \mathbb{E}_\theta \left[
 \dfrac{\partial ^2}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^\text{T}} \log p\left(X| {\theta}\right)\right]=-n \mathbb{E}_\theta \left[
 \dfrac{\partial ^2}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^\text{T}} \log \int p\left(X| m,{\theta}\right)p(m)\,\text{d}m \right]$$

Comment: I am not absolutely sure about the way you define the likelihood in the model. Here, you seem to consider the conditional likelihood of $x_i$ given $m_i$. But I guess the original question implies that $m_i$ is a hidden variable, to which we do not have access. If this is the case, we should define the likelihood of the observations as $p(x_i|\theta) = \sum_{m_i}p(x_i|m_i,\theta)p(m_i)$